# I was trying to create a 3d sphere behind my hero image using three js but i keep getting TypeError: Create is not a function

Tags: next.js, three.js

This is the error i am getting.
In My case i think when i use OrbitControls and Sphere, i am getting this error and without sphere how am i suppose to create an sphere. please let me know how to fix this error or is there any alternate method to create a 3d sphere
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgtDI.png)

My index.js

```
import ParticlesContainer from "@/components/ParticlesContainer";
import { MeshDistortMaterial, OrbitControls, Sphere } from "@react-three/drei";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import Image from "next/image";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import ReactTyped from "react-typed";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className="h-full">
      <div className="w-full h-full flex flex-row">
        <div
          className="text-center w-full flex flex-col xl:flex xl:flex-row items-center mt-20 xl:mt-0
        h-full container mx-auto gap-10"
        >
          <div className="w-[700px] mx-auto">
            <h1 className="font-semibold text-7xl tracking-tight text-[#CAB3DA]">
              Hi!, I am Arsh
            </h1>
            <div className="flex w-full font-semibold gap-2 text-4xl justify-center items-center">
              <h1 className="">A Front End Web</h1>
              <ReactTyped
                className="text-[#6C56C1]"
                strings={["Developer", "Designer", "UI / UX Designer"]}
                typeSpeed={120}
                backSpeed={140}
                loop
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <ParticlesContainer />
          <div className="mx-auto">
            <div>
              <Canvas>
                <Suspense fallback={null}>
                  <OrbitControls enableZoom={false} />
                  <ambientLight intensity={1} />
                  <directionalLight position={[3, 2, 1]} />
                  <Sphere args={[1, 100, 200]} scale={2.4}>
                    <MeshDistortMaterial
                      color="#3d1c56"
                      attach="material"
                      distort={0.5}
                      speed={2}
                    />
                  </Sphere>
                </Suspense>
              </Canvas>
            </div>
            <Image
              className="img"
              alt="header"
              width={400}
              height={400}
              src="/test.svg"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```